# How do you catch incorrect location pathnames in React Router when using the <Router> component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Say you've structure your react app this way with react-router:

```
const rootRoute = {
    childRoutes: [ {
        path: '/',
        component: require( './components/Layout' ),
        childRoutes: [
            require('./routes/HelloBeautiful'),
            require('./routes/GreetingsEarthlings'), ... (etc.)
        ]
    }]
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}
                routes={rootRoute}>      
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById( 'root' )
);
```

You want to redirect the user to the HelloBeautiful route if they attempt to go to one of the routes not specified in the rootRoute constant's childRoutes.

You could implement a check inside of componentWillReceiveProps or componentDidUpdate in your Layout.js to compare the location props against the master list of child routes, but that seems tedious.

What do you do? The other related questions I found regarding this were addressing a different react-router style with the  component.

---

EDIT:

implemented @stkvtflw 's answer like this:

`Layout.js` render:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children || <Welcome/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

`index.js` rootRoute

```
 const rootRoute = {
        childRoutes: [ {
            path: '/',
            component: require( './components/Layout' ),
            childRoutes: [
                require('./routes/HelloBeautiful'),
                require('./routes/GreetingsEarthlings'), //... (etc.)
                { path: '*' } // don't need to require a component here
            ]
        }]
    }
```

`Welcome.js` componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    browserHistory.push('/hellobeautiful')
}
```

Didn't need to create a PageNotFound component because the desired behavior is just to redirect upon a broken link.

Comment: create the last child route with `path: '*'`. It should help

Comment: @stkvtflw How exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a route with `*` path.

```
const rootRoute = {
    childRoutes: [ {
        path: '/',
        component: require( './components/Layout' ),
        childRoutes: [
            require('./routes/HelloBeautiful'),
            require('./routes/GreetingsEarthlings'), ... (etc.)
        ]
    }, 
    ...
    {
        path: '*',
        component: require( './components/NotFoundPage' ),
    }]
}
```